# Multiple collections in an object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following object

```
public class bizObj
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int p_id { get; set; }
    public string acc_number { get; set; }
    public string a_name { get; set; }
    public string a_phone { get; set; }
    public virtual product product { get; set; }
    public virtual account account { get; set; }
}
```

Linq statment to get data from db is

```
 public IEnumerable<bizObj> GetbizObj(int id)
        {
            var acs = (from c in db.p_account
                            where c.p_id==id
                            select new bizObj
                            {    
                                name = c.p_name,
                                p_id = c.product.id,
                                acc_number=c.account.acc_number,
                                a_name = c.a_name,
                                a_phone = c.a_phone
                            });    
                       return acs;
        }
```

The above code is working fine but it is returning one collection. What I am trying to 
get is that it has a collection of

```
 {
     name,
     p_id
//than a second collection which has all the records that have same name ane p_id
         {
               acc_number,
               a_name
               a_phone
          }
       }
```

Please let me know how I can accomplish this using linq/lambda expression. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear - `acc_number`, `a_name` and `a_phone` are properties of `bizObj` - what collection you want?

Comment: Basically i.e name=xyz company and p_id=123 than xyz company might have record of 100 people who have  acc_number a_name and a_phone I want it to return one object with collection in it so that xyz company p_id than list of 100 people in that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is unclear, but it looks like you're saying you want to group rows by `name` and `p_id`.

```
var query = acs.GroupBy(x => new { x.name, x.p_id })
    .Select(g => new { g.Key.name, g.Key.p_id, Items = g.ToList() });
```

Comment: No what i mean is. i.e name=xyz company, p_id=123 ...xyz company has collection of people with a_name, a_phone and acc_number